# How many realms can contain Realm Object Server (free developer edition)?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

Is it possible to use one server for e.g. 100 000 users (each has own realm for data backup)? How effectively it performs with such big data?

Comment: There is no user limit. The enterprise edition gives server-side change event listener hooks for NodeJS, and the ability to write to the ROS from NodeJS.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks a lot! I just met a mention somewhere that a ROS can contain only 256 realms. Glad to see it is not true :)

Comment: well we can invoke @ChristianMelchior but I haven't heard of such limitation. That wouldn't be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limitation on the number of Realms that the server can handle (other than the physical limitations of the machine). By this, I mean that the Developer Edition does not include any hardcoded/virtual limits to push people over to the Enterprise Edition.

I don't know where you heard the 256 limit from, but it's wrong :).

From https://realm.io/pricing/:

> No cost to use, no matter how much you use it, even in production for commercial use cases.

Comment: Is there any documentation pointing to the hardware requirements for real-world scenarios with 100k, 1M, 10M users etc. Great to know there is no user limit!